# Out of memory error upon closing a workbook - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, memory, out-of-memory, userform

I am using a userform with a couple of dropdown combo boxes to pull data into this workbook from an external workbook.

The external work is opened within the Userform_Initialise macro and the combo boxes are populated:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Open criteria database
    Dim X As String
    X = ThisWorkbook.path

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=X & "\Criteria database.xlsm"

    'Number of non-unique clients in DB
    Dim noClients As Integer
    noClients = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Criteria database").Sheets("Screen decisions").Range("A:A")) - 1

    'define array for client names
    Dim clientArray() As String
    Dim j As Integer: j = 1
    ReDim clientArray(1 To noClients)

    'populate array of non-unique clients
    Do Until j = noClients + 1
        clientArray(j) = Workbooks("Criteria database").Sheets("Screen decisions").Range("A" & j + 1).value
        j = j + 1
    Loop

    'Now that we have non-unique clients, remove those that are duplicates
    Dim uClients As New Collection, a
    Dim i As Long

    'Adds only unique collections
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In clientArray
       uClients.Add a, a
    Next

    For Each a In uClients
        clientBox.AddItem a
    Next

    'Memory handling
    Set uClients = Nothing
    Erase clientArray()

End Sub
```

The workbook stays open whilst the user makes their selections from the combo boxes. Following the selections, the relevant data is dragged in from the open workbook and then the workbook is closed:

```
Sub OK_Click()

    Me.Hide

    'define sheets
    Dim sd As Worksheet
    Set sd = Workbooks("Criteria database").Sheets("Screen decisions")

    Dim lt As Worksheet
    Set lt = Workbooks("Criteria database").Sheets("Lookup table")

    Dim cc As Worksheet
    Set cc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current client")

    cc.Range("A5:BZ50").ClearContents 'clear current client data

    'find current client and portfolio row
    Dim curC As String
    curC = clientBox.value

    Dim curP As String
    curP = portfolioBox.value

    Dim lrow As Integer
    lrow = sd.Cells(sd.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim a As Integer 
    Dim nm As Name 'Current named range
    Dim nmstr As String 'string name of range
    Dim topRng As Range 'Top row range
    Dim col As Integer 'first column in range
    Dim crit As Range 'used to loop through cells in current range
    Dim c As Integer: c = 2 'Keeps track of current client column
    Dim r As Integer 'Keeps track of current client row
    Dim critCol As Integer 'current criteria screening value
    Dim tRow As Integer 'lookup table row in criteria database

    For i = 2 To lrow

        'Stop when we get to the correct position
        If sd.Cells(i, 1).value = curC And sd.Cells(i, 2).value = curP Then

            For Each nm In Workbooks("Criteria database").Names 'Looping through the named ranges

                nmstr = Right(nm.RefersTo, Len(nm.RefersTo) - 19)
                nmstr = Replace(nmstr, "$", "")
                Set topRng = sd.Range(nmstr)
                col = topRng.Column 'First column in range

                If sd.Cells(i, col).value <> "None" Then 'If 1st criteria isn't "None" then it is in use

                    tRow = Application.Match(nm.Name, lt.Range("A:A"), 0)
                    cc.Cells(5, c).value = lt.Cells(tRow, 3).value 'lock in formatted named range
                    r = 6 'reset row

                    For Each crit In topRng

                        cc.Cells(r, c).Value2 = crit.Value2
                        critCol = crit.Column
                        cc.Cells(r, c + 1).Value2 = sd.Cells(i, critCol).Value2
                        r = r + 1

                    Next crit

                    c = c + 2

                End If

            Next nm

            Exit For

        End If

    Next i


    Set sd = Nothing
    Set lt = Nothing
    cc.Activate
    Set cc = Nothing
    Set topRng = Nothing

    Workbooks("Criteria database").Close SaveChanges:=False 'PROBLEM LINE

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

When you run this code as it is above I get an "Out of memory" error message from the VBA editor. The help link takes you here:

[Out of memory (Error 7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/out-of-memory-error-7)

I have tried many of the solutions on this page but nothing seems to stop the error other than to comment out the line of code that closes the external workbook:

```
'Workbooks("Criteria database").Close SaveChanges:=False 'PROBLEM LINE
```

Does anyone know why Excel is struggling with memory here? The external workbook is only 216Kb whereas the one that is running the code is 6.3Mb. In other macros, I frequently jump in and out of other workbooks with no issues.

**UPDATE:** Saving and using the external workbook as a .xlsx file also seems to solve the problem. Not a total as the external really needs to be .xlsm but at least it's something...

**UPDATE:** Closing the VBA Editor before initialising the userform also solves the memory issue... no idea why:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by having user forms hidden but not unloaded when closing a workbook.  I added the following code to the workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  'close any open forms
  Do While UserForms.Count > 0
    Unload UserForms(0)
  Loop
End Sub
```

This fixed the problem for me.